# RMI: Does the client have to have all implementations or just interfaces?

Tags: java, architecture, rmi

Does client have to have all implementations or just interfaces?

In details: let we have remote interface Foo:

```
public interface Foo extends Remote {
    FooMessage getFooMessage () throws RemoteException;
    void setFooMessage (FooMessage fm) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Communication between client and server is happening by means of FooMessage.

```
public interface FooMessage {
    String getMsg ();
    void setMsg (String str);  
}
```

The client is very simple:

```
public void clientCode () {
    Foo foo = (Foo)Naming.lookup ("rmi://localhost/FooService");
    FooMessage msg = foo.getFooMessage ();
    msg.setMsg ("asdf");
    foo.setFooMessage (msg);
}
```

Both Foo and FooMessage should have concrete implementations on server side. The question is: should client have these implementations too or RMI mechanism transfers implementations implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete implementation class [*can* be loaded by the client from the server,](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html) using an RMI class loader. However, there are a common "gotchas" to keep in mind:

1. The RMI class loader is disabled unless the client has a `SecurityManager` installed. This is intended to restrict the actions of any malicious code served to the client.
2. The server needs to specify a "codebase" that is accessible to the client. This could be a `file:` URL on a shared file system, an `http:` server, etc. This is specified with the `java.rmi.server.codebase` system property.

(Also note: the linked guide is useful, but it talks a lot about "stubs"; since Java 5, it is most common to use stubs generated dynamically at runtime by the client. The mechanism applies to any other classes that need to be shared, however.)

Comment: The client needs FooMessageImpl, but not FooImpl.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, the client's implementation of `Foo` is just a stub, implemented dynamically by the RMI runtime. It's responsible for communicating with the real `FooImpl` that runs on the server.